# О чём-то(,) да говорит

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая в названии? Если да, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**О чём-то да говорит** (частица).

***О чем-то, да говорит*** (союз: хотя о чем-то немногом, да говорит).

Здесь два варианта: ДА в значении усилительной частицы или союза.

Значение союза ДА из словаря: 4. (присоединяет предл. и чл. предл.). Выражает противопоставление, несоответствие или ОГРАНИЧЕНИЕ предшествующего; но, однако.

**Примеры**

1) **Да ― союз, подчеркивается местоимение**

Между тем на 23 октября намечен релиз « Горько-2», и любая шумиха ― на пользу грядущей премьере. Но даже если такой гений маркетинга, как Бекмамбетов, отказывается участвовать в « движухе» с письмом, это **о чЁм-то, да** **говорит**.

2) **Да ― усилительная частица, подчеркивается (усиливается) глагол**

Владимир Владимирович был принят британской королевой по разряду царствующих особ. Это **о чем-то да говорИт**?

Comment: Дискуссия под моим ответом.

Comment: Ответ нашёлся в словаре Ушакова.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно без запятой.

"Да" здесь имеет исключительно усилительное значение. Его нельзя заменить на "но" по смыслу, а можно заменить на частицу "и".

`(А это уже) о чём-то да говорит.`
`(А это уже) о чём-то и говорит.`

В подтверждение в гугл-книгах написание без запятой.

**Update:**
Из словаря Ушакова:
5. в знач. усилительной частицы. В середине предложения употр. для усиления значения того слова, перед которым стоит. *Вашими бы устами да мед пить!* | То же после неопределенных местоимений и наречий (*что-нибудь, сколько-нибудь, как-нибудь* и т.п.). *Это что-нибудь да значит. Он когда-нибудь да вернется. Что-нибудь да осталось же?*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145365/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Дал свой ответ, как вы и просили.

Comment: Что касается второго предложения, о котором вы говорили, то там просто нет запятой, так как оба предложения односоставные. Мне лень писать ответ.

Comment: Но меня там не ответ волнует, а неоднородность, из-за которой "и" не очень в тему. Это в штыки восприняли (один).

Comment: @JimKorbett О комментарии выше было оповещение?

Comment: Да, я посмотрю.

Comment: Под ответом тоже есть обсуждение этого.

Comment: @JimKorbett Например, такие предложения: *Мне ясно, и только не понимаю это. Там как раз темно, и только зарядка светится.* Нет однородности, "и" не в тему. Там предложение такого типа.

Answer (score 1):

Взгляните на выделенные слова в следующих примерах:

> Это **определённо** вызовет у нас проблемы.
> Я **действительно** не хочу такую работу.
> Это **несомненно** лучшее решение.
> Я **обязательно** решу эту проблему.

Обычно в книгах с классификациями частиц такие слова относят к подмножеству утвердительных частиц. Когда слово ‟да” следует после неопределённых местоимений или частиц, оно также является такой утвердительной частицей. Взгляните на примеры:

> Выбрасывай множество ударов, чем-нибудь да попадёшь. (Можно заменить на ‟чем-нибудь обязательно попадёшь”.)
> Учителя хорошо о ней отзывались во всех трёх школах, где она училась, – это что-нибудь да значит. (Можно заменить на ‟что-нибудь обязательно значит”.)

‟Да” в данном случае не заменяется ‟но”, так как здесь нет противительного отношения. Не следует путать с такими ситуациями, как в следующем предложении: ‟Поздно, но приду”. Здесь как раз есть противительное отношение, и это предложение является неполным от предложения ‟Поздно приду, но приду”.

В итоге правильный вариант пунктуации – без запятой: ‟О чём-то да говорит”.

Comment: Вы подсказали хороший аргумент. Здесь проблема проявляется в следующем: *Мало говорит, но говорит* — нормально. *О чём-то говорит, но говорит* — бред. Но он ничего не слышит.

Comment: (Это он минусует. У меня тоже минус.)

Comment: У вас же предлог пропущен: *попадёшь **во** что-нибудь* (или не понимаю).

Comment: Ещё мне кажется, что в вашем примере "приду" не подразумевается: *— Когда ты будешь? — Поздно, но приду.* Или: *— Придёшь поздно? — Поздно, но приду.*

Comment: Нет, здесь всё правильно: – Ты придёшь? – Поздно, но приду.

Comment: По поводу удара, то лучше заменить на ‟чем-нибудь да попадёшь”, то есть хуком или прямым. Хотя и тот вариант был правильным.

Comment: Интересный контекст для пропуска. Теперь ясно.

Comment: Чего правильным? Вообще его не понимаю.

Comment: Может и неправильный, не хочу спорить об этом.

Comment: Бывают разговорные варианты (понятные, но не совсем корректные), но этот вообще не удаётся понять. Просто нет согласования. "Куда-нибудь" там хорошо подходит.

Comment: Хорошо, это неправильный вариант.

Comment: У Sharon изначально было: *Хотя о чём-то, да говорит.* Но потом она поняла, что это ерунда, и добавила "немногом". Честно поступила? Нет. Оно делает фразу гораздо корректнее: *О чём-то немногом говорит, но говорит.* "Чём-то" можно выкинуть: *О немногом говорит, но говорит.* Чтобы было полностью корректно, не должно быть отрицания ("не"), но это очень сложно.