# Опускается ли второе тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, приложение

> Отец — капитан первого ранга (—) и старший брат — мичман (—) погибли  в русско-японской войне.

Comment: Принимаете неправильные ответы, в которых нет ни примеров, ни правила. Странно. В ответе такой вариант получается: *Отец-капитан и брат-мичман...* То есть не приложение. А единое понятие там не подходит.

Comment: Вы свой вариант ответа не предложили.

Comment: По правилам второе тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая.

Comment: Запятая тут может стоять только при приложении, однако ее мы целенаправленно ставить не будем. ТО, что могли быть поставлены две запятые, не является критерием того, что второе тире нужно опустить, иначе бы не существовало двойного тире при приложениях вообще, т.к. всегда можно приложение обособить таким образом.

Comment: Нет, по условиям контекста, то есть того, что вокруг приложения.

Comment: В данном случае контекст никак не влияет на знак, который должен стоять при приложении, правила, запрещающего ставить двойное тире в данном случае нет.

Comment: Лучше сказать, что нет подходящего правила, чтобы опустить второе тире.

Comment: Вот, вы сами на свой вопрос дали ответ: двойное тире оправдано.  После "тире "запятую не поставил  в предыдущем посте.

Comment: У меня не было вопроса) А какой ещё у меня мог быть ответ, если я против варианта с одним тире? Про пост не понял.

Comment: "По правилам второе тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая", - ваши слова.

Comment: Вы за вариант с тире и запятой, как я понял.

Comment: Ужас, а откуда запятой-то взяться? Имел в виду, что тире не опускается, раз нет запятой.

Comment: Напишите пример с вашими знаками.

Comment: Просто убрать скобки (4 тире). Но лучше с запятыми (без тире), у Розенталя нет ни одного примера с личностями и тире (в таких случаях запятые ставятся, как видим).

Comment: По примерам Розенталя можно заметить, что тире ставятся, когда даётся название или поясняется смысл слова.

Comment: Об этом варианте я и говорил.

Comment: @Oleed, вы пишете: "Отец-капитан и брат-мичман". А что должно получится? Капитан первого ранга и мичман являются приложениями. Следовательно, отделяются с помощью тире.

Comment: @Серж Этот вариант без пауз не особо удачен. "Отец-капитан" ещё можно встретить, но "капитан первого ранга" явно пояснение (с паузами), а не часть единого понятия.

Comment: @oleed, безусловно, кто об этом спорит?! Разве у меня часть единого понятия?

Comment: @Серж Да, когда одно тире (без запятой), то часть единого понятия по правилу Лопатина. Для пояснения необходима вторая пауза!

Comment: Какое правило Лопатина? Единое понятие, это например, отец-пьяница и подобные, пишущиеся через дефис.

Comment: @Серж Вот это правило: http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php

Comment: Ну, как это правило связано с этим вопросом? Дело не в паузе здесь. Там же четко написано: если есть пробел, примеры с неоднословными приложениями. Здесь, как вы сами верно заметили, пояснение. Следовательно, или тире или запятые. Ну или скобки. Хотя скобки не очень удачны.

Comment: @Серж Только два тире, а не одно, обособленное приложение не бывает с одним знаком, иначе оно не обособленное и получается то, что в этом правиле.

Comment: На маяке жил только сторож — старый глухой швед (Пауст.)  - здесь тоже,по-вашему, тот же пункт?

Comment: Пример из справочника Лопатина и и этот пример - это два связаны с друг другом.

Comment: Ну что вы делаете? Это приложение в конце предложения. Если бы предложение продолжалось, то ставилось бы второе тире!

Comment: @Oleed Вы пишете, что при обособленном приложении должна быть вторая пауза. Вот и я привел второй пример. Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её  О людях  — жертвах жизни.... Здесь тоже, по вашему, единое понятие?

Comment: Продолжение под принятым ответом. Здесь всё, чтобы не ушло в чат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В параграфе Розенталя «[Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)», где говорится, что «одно тире (первое или второе) опускается» (примечание к пункту 10), нет подходящего случая. Хотя есть такой пример:
*Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её.*
Тогда по аналогии пишем:
*Отец — капитан первого ранга и старший брат — мичман — погибли в русско-японской войне.*
Но такая запись по крайней мере нелогична, несимметрична. Да и нельзя ориентироваться только на один пример из справочника (в нём, кстати, не возникает неясности, чему среди прочего способствует повторение предлога «о»). Каждое предложение нужно рассматривать индивидуально, и желательно в контексте. Например, в каких-нибудь досье, анкетах, сводках целесообразнее приложения заключить в скобки:
*Отец (капитан первого ранга) и старший брат (мичман) погибли в русско-японской войне.*

Без третьего тире вообще непонятная конструкция получается:
*Отец — капитан первого ранга и старший брат — мичман погибли в русско-японской войне.*

Можно написать так:
*Отец — капитан первого ранга — и старший брат — мичман — погибли в русско-японской войне.*
Но зачем такой горизонтальный частокол? Да и не тянут приложения на пояснения-разъяснения, когда тире предпочтительней.

Самый, на мой взгляд, оптимальный вариант — это запятые:
*Отец, капитан первого ранга, и старший брат, мичман, погибли в русско-японской войне.*

P. S.: Я сразу отметил этот вопрос, так как тоже сталкивался с такими конструкциями и интересовался их пунктуацией. Всё не получалось ответить — и вот, благодаря «вмешательству» oleedd'а (спасибо!)...

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить, что в этом примере Розенталя "дефисные тире" (*люди-жертвы и люди-владыки*), здесь такое не подходит. Розенталь не разобрался с этим и смешал эти примеры со всем остальным. Здесь явный его промах (наверно, самый существенный). У Лопатина уже говорится о таком тире, но о ситуациях, описанных Розенталем, не сказано (наверно, из-за их редкости). А с третьим тире вроде бы ещё непонятнее.

Comment: Удивительная манера  у наших участников — брать на себя право критиковать маститых лингвистов.

Comment: @Серж Ну у него нет очень важного правила, а примеры, относящиеся к нему, перемешаны со всем остальным. Это чуть ли не единственное, за что могу критиковать. А в остальном надо было написать больше по сложным моментам.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец, здесь два приложения и два тире. Непонятно, зачем ставить тире перед союзом и. Вариант с тремя тире тоже неудачный.

Comment: @Серж Чтобы всё было предельно ясно. В том же приложении есть пример: *Над проектом работали конструктор, инженер — специалист по связи — и радист.*  Странно, почему Вы не ставите запятую после первого приложения, но ставите после второго: "Отец, капитан первого ранга и старший брат, мичман, погибли..."  Чем это отличается от варианта с тире?

Comment: А чем отличается этот пример? Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её (М. Г.). В примере, который вы привели. ясно сказано: Однако, если возможно двоякое толкование фразы, ставится и второе тире: Над проектом работали конструктор, инженер — специалист по связи — и радист (при отсутствии второго тире получится, что инженер был одновременно и радистом).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Разве в нашем примере есть двусмысленность? Здесь приложения относятся к однородным членам предложения, связанных союзом и. Зачем запятая после приложения "капитан первого ранга"? Если, конечно, речь идет об этой запятой.

Comment: @Серж При обособленном приложении (пояснительном) должна быть вторая пауза. И всё здесь. Это незыблемо. Это как отступление, вставка. Учитесь понимать что-то самостоятельно, а не только в правилах читать. Вы же видите, что правила никто развивать, дополнять не собирается, потому что деньги не дают на это.

Comment: А вот Александр правильно сказал, не надо ориентироваться только на один пример из справочника. Розенталь вообще неправильно понял пример Горького. Там не обособленные приложения, так как их нельзя изъять.

Comment: Пока у нас есть правила и мы должны на них ориентироваться. Ну как можно считать себя превыше Розенталя? Розенталь не понял, вы поняли., Да уж. Ладно, давайте на этом закроем обсуждение. бесполезно спорить с человеком, который считает, что лучше разбирается в лингвистике, чем знаменитый лингвист,

Comment: @Серж Пример "о людях" в своём ответе я привёл как единственный в этой теме без второго тире перед "и". Но он всё равно не является аксиомой, у него другая структура, в нём, например, нет продолжения после второго приложения. А пример с "радистом" как раз и показывает, что тире перед "и" допустимо/необходимо. И пусть в нашем примере нет двусмысленности, но всё-таки без второго тире получается каша: *Отец – капитан и старший брат...* // А если Вы опускаете оба вторых тире, то опускайте тогда и обе запятые – что за знаковая дискриминация? :)

Comment: @Серж Недочёты в справочниках многие люди видят, в том числе Sharon. Плохо, что вы не можете, уровень обычного учителя... Да, там единые понятия. Обособленные приложения можно изъять, а здесь получается: *Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях и о людях.*

Comment: Пример с "людьми" как раз подпадает и под наш пример. Хотя и нет продолжения. Давайте возьмем такой пример с одиночным приложением.  Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии. Если бы здесь было бы два приложения вы бы поставили бы какой- нибудь знак после приложения?

Comment: И зачем нагромождать тире?

Comment: @Серж Нет, кукушка – определяемое слово, глашатай – приложение. Об этом и говорится в соответствующем пункте. // А я и не нагромождаю, я за запятые.

Comment: Я бы сказал недосказанность. Невозможно все описать. видеть недочету там, где их нет. Почему бы тогда вам не написать правила самим? Напишите и пошлите в институт русского языка.

Comment: @Серж Это другое правило. Здесь приложение перед определяемым словом. Правило такое: 3) Если приложение предшествует определяемому существительному. Эти случаи настолько редкие, что Лопатин и не стал их рассматривать. Это как экзотика. И если было бы обособленное приложение, то было бы "известил", а не "известила". Да, невозможно всё описать, но возможно дополнять (что делать они не собираются). Правила надо составлять коллективно, Розенталь не работал сам, но вся слава досталась ему.

Comment: Надо дополнять, никто не спорит. У нас есть Академический справочник. А постоянно выпускать новые работы - работа трудоемкая.

Comment: Основная часть работы была его.

Comment: Не факт, в Википедии он и Былинский идут наравне. Можно сделать онлайн-справочник и дополнять его, сейчас 21 век. А в академическом в разы меньше, чем у Розенталя, так что лучше дополнять Розенталя. А там авторские права, их даже не удосужились выкупить как общественное достояние. Наверно, лучшим вариантом было бы создание примечаний или статей. А ещё ж есть стилистика, там вообще тёмный лес, правила перекрывают около 1%. Но умные люди там и без правил могут разбираться.

Comment: Что касается справочника по стилистики   -он очень полезный, несмотря на свой минимум. Язык меняется, нужен новой справочник. А насколько мне известно, это единственный справочник такого рода. По крайне мере мне неизвестны другие справочники такого рода. Обычно в справочниках по стилистике описываются всякие тропы, функциональные стили, и т.д.

Comment: *Язык меняется, нужен новой справочник* — ничего устаревшего в справочниках Розенталя не вижу. Анализ конкретных словосочетаний плохо подходит для справочников, но здесь словари очень помогают. А вот структурных и смысловых вещей очень не хватает. Там много всего есть, бывает, что сложность аж зашкаливает (здесь ещё относительно простые вещи обсуждаются). Необходимо создать реестр того, чего нет в правилах. Написал Грамоте на emale, но ответа нет, они ничего без денег (прямого финансирования) делать не станут.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, ответы и сама дискуссия показались **мне интересными**, но не хотелось бы начинать с определения правильности предложенных решений и академичности справочников  Розенталя и ПАС. Я не люблю **однозначных суждений**, но понимаю, что они тоже закономерны. Этому учит нас природа: из множества виртуальных возможностей тонкого мира в конечном итоге  в материи проявляется  что-то одно. Попробуем найти это **конкретное решение**.

Определяем **возможности письменных вариантов**. Их всего три (одно тире, два тире и запятые), и они не выглядят запрещенными. Два варианта есть в справочнике Розенталя:  *Ловили рыбу бреднем — маленьким неводом — да вёршами-ловушками; Достали глубиномер — гирьку на длинной бечёвке — и промерили глубину. Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её (М. Г.).*

Добавим сюда третий вариант (обособление запятыми), и сравним их **по семантике, графике и интонации.**

(1) Вариант с обособлением  двумя тире

***Отец — капитан первого ранга — и старший брат — мичман — погибли в русско-японской войне.***

(2) Вариант с обособлением  одним тире
***Отец — капитан первого ранга и старший брат — мичман погибли в русско-японской войне.***

(3) Вариант с обособлением  запятыми

***Отец, капитан первого ранга, и старший брат, мичман, погибли в русско-японской войне.***

**В первом варианте** (два тире) использована **вставочная** конструкция. По Розенталю, он используется **для выделения** (с двух сторон) приложения, носящего характер **пояснения.** При таком пояснении дополнительный характер информации подчеркнут: два тире, две паузы, общее понижение тона для сообщения.

**Во втором варианте** (одно тире, по Розенталю)   информация дана  для внесения **ясности, если приложение** относится к одному из однородных членов предложения. В этом случае приложение более тесно связано с основным содержанием, но **четко выделено.**

**В третьем варианте** связь приложения с предложением также  присутствует, но при этом конструкция не обозначена так четко и является более сложной для прочтения.

**Вывод:**  Поэтому лучше выбрать второй вариант (с одним тире):

*Отец — капитан первого ранга и старший брат — мичман // погибли в русско-японской войне.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145482/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Хорошо, правила есть правила, и мы обязуемся соблюдать их.  Извините нас.  По возможности я всегда к этому стремлюсь и даю второй ответ-комментарий. Просто иногда обсуждение ответа не менее важно, чем сам ответ. В этом случае мне приходится копировать и сохранять материал лично для себя. Ведь обсуждения из чата могут удаляться. А про возможность обсуждения в Мете я и не знала.

Comment: Не для такого внесения ясности, а (из оригинального справочника): Для отделения приложения от одного из однородных членов, к которому приложение относится (чтобы не смешивать приложения с однородным членом). То есть чтобы было ясно, где приложение, а где однородный член. Здесь смешано: *Отец, капитан первого ранга, старший брат, мичман.* Будто четыре человека. А по правилу: *Отец — капитан первого ранга, старший брат — мичман.* При "и" такое внесение ясности уже не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, тире нужны – это же вставная конструкция. Не ставить их – всё равно что написать только открывающую скобку.

Answer (score 1):

Пример, который вы приводите, может быть оформлен следующим образом.

Отец — капитан первого ранга и старший брат — мичман погибли в русско-японской войне.

Отец, капитан первого ранга и старший брат, мичман, погибли в русско-японской войне.

Вариант с вставной конструкцией  был бы возможен, если в предложении было бы одно приложение. Т к. по правилу,
если внутри вставной конструкции уже имеется тире, то общим выделительным знаком могут быть только скобки: Между тем лесок, который я недавно проехал (какой там лесок — осиновые кустики!), до сих пор сливавшийся с чернотой ночи, так что его нельзя было и заподозрить, начал смутно проступать (Сол.). Если выделить одно приложение скобками,другое с помощью тире, нарушается симметрия знаков.

Что касается тире перед союзом "и", то между однородными приложениями,соединёнными союзом "и",никакого пунктуационно знака не требуется.
Подробнее об оформлении вставной конструкций,см.:

[Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128)

Дополнение от 13.05.2023 г.

Я специально обратился в ИРЯ РАН. Вот ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но это не вставная конструкция вовсе, приложение, которое является поясняющим элементом предложения. Какое именно правило позволяет "опустить" второе тире?

Comment: Серж, союз "и" не соединяет здесь однородные приложения: "старший брат" не приложение к "отцу".  // Ссылка совсем не открывается. Может, имели в виду [это](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец,,союз и соединяет два приложения:  капитан первого ранга и мичман. При чем первое приложение относится к нарицательному существительному "отец" второе —  к нарицательному сущ-му "брат".

Comment: Ссылку исправил.

Comment: @Ajgy, все верно, это не вставная конструкция. Я об этом и пишу.

Comment: Союз соединяет, прежде всего, субъектов, определяемые слова здесь "отец" и "старший брат". А уже к ним добавляются приложения, описывающие их.

Comment: Да, между ними не нужно тире.

Comment: Уж очень противоречивый у вас ответ, Серж...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, а конкретнее?

Comment: @Серж Спасибо за ответ ИРЯ! Но... Я тоже считаю, что при обособлении запятыми приложения *капитан первого ранга* вторая запятая нужна. Изобразила ответ. В нем есть мнение "Грамоты".

Comment: Двусмысленность при таком оформлении (единое понятие и "обособленное" приложение), поэтому не пойдёт. Ну и вторая пауза в речи никуда не девается.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, запятая была пропущена по недосмотру. Но спор был насчет тире.

Comment: По недосмотру? Вот Вы сами пишете в комментарии: *Здесь приложения относятся к однородным членам предложения, связанных союзом и. Зачем запятая после приложения "капитан первого ранга"? Если, конечно, речь идет об этой запятой.* Ведь нужна же, правда? Так добавьте, пожалуйста. И *плюсище* будет вашим — с превеликим удовольствием!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ну Базаров формально отнёсся к правилу. У Розенталя: [Тире вместо запятой ставится] Для отделения приложения от одного из однородных членов, к которому приложение относится (**чтобы не смешивать приложения с однородным членом**). В данном случае ничего не смешивается.

Comment: @Серж В будущем давайте ссылку на вопрос. Чтобы они были в курсе всех проблем. Это даст возможность получить не формальный и более объективный ответ.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, речь шла о тире, а не о запятой.

Answer (score 1):

В справочника Розенталя[, в главе про приложения,](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111) есть примечание в самом конце главы, состоящее из 9 пунктов. Я так понял, что вас интересует то, применяется ли пункт 4 к вашему примеру, то есть опускание второго тире при однородных членах. Вот данный пункт целиком:

> 4. для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения: В оранжерее разводились магнолии, камелии — цветы Японии, орхидеи и цикламены; За столом сидели хозяйка дома, её сестра — подруга моей жены, двое незнакомых мне лиц, моя жена и я; Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её (М. Г.).

Данный пункт является ошибочным. Отсутствие тире в **первом и втором примере (про цветы и людей за столом)** объясняется пунктом 1 в этом же примечании, где сказано, что второе тире опускается, если после обособляемого приложения стоит запятая. Вот примеры из этого пункта:

> Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров; Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух (Газ.)

Отсутствие запятой **в третьем примере (про неравенство, условия, людей-жертв)** объясняется тем, что определение и приложение равноправны, то есть как в сочетаниях офицер-ракетчик, художник-самоучка, соседка-педагог, но только с приложением, состоящим из более чем одного слова. Вот несколько примеров: старшего лейтенанта — артиллериста, участников войны — инвалидов, у научного сотрудника — космонавта.  Этот пункт есть в справочнике Лопатина [(вот тут, самый первый пункт)](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php).

В этом пункте (4-й пункт, про опускание второго тире) написано, что причина опускания тире во внесении ясности, то есть чтобы было понятно, к какому однородному относится обособляемое приложение, но если есть **союз между однородными**, то у нас не может возникнуть проблемы в понимании, к какому однородному относится обособляемое приложение. Некоторым участникам форума не помешало бы иногда включать собственную голову, а не слепо верить авторитетам, какую бы бессмысленную чушь они ни писали.

Comment: Согласен с вами во всём (впервые), тоже это всё заметил. Этот пункт о постановке тире вместо запятой, а попал не туда.

Comment: Я помню, что вы давали ссылку на Лопатина в каком-то ответе про вот этот самый случай, когда приложение и определяемое слово равноправны. Дайте её ещё раз, чтобы я дополнил ответ.

Comment: А она есть, в комментариях под вопросом, странно, что вы не прочитали всё имеющееся перед тем, как отвечать (вдруг чей-то ответ повторите). О дефисном тире в комментариях сказал, а вот о дублировании правила промолчал, такое у Розенталя несколько раз замечал.

Comment: Да, нашёл. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете что-то здесь сказать? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454429 Мне нужна поддержка. Это голосование за неправильные ответы... В чате под моим ответом дискуссия, прочитайте, там много интересного.

Comment: Ну ответ Sharon там определённо чушь. Чтобы что-то было союзом оно должно соединять некие однородные элементы, как однородные члены или предложения. Там определённо ‟да” является частицей. Но чтобы дать ответ или поддержать, мне нужно расписать всё подробно, а для этого нужно понять всё отчётливо и провести определённую работу. Сейчас я не очень хочу этим заниматься. Но плюс могу поставить просто потому, что по сравнению с ответом Sharon, который принят и имеет множество плюсов, ваш ответ просто заслуживает лингвистический оскар.

Comment: Вот именно, то же самое говорю, а они игнорируют это. Вы чат читали? Видите, какие там аргументы? Мол, звучит с "но" нормально. На самом деле не нормально. Потом нашёлся в Нацкорпусе более-менее звучащий пример... Но он неправильный.

Comment: Спасибо, круто сказано.

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы вы чат прочитали. То, что тянет на оскар, там... Кое-какое открытие получилось сделать...

Comment: Как-нибудь почитаю.

Comment: Жду отзыв......

Comment: Мы ещё не закончили. Там щас накал. Не сдаюсь...

Comment: Помогите. Там уже заявляют про грамматическую корректность (её нет): https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145365 И ещё гляньте моё замечание про ограничение (помню, вы о нём говорили) и другое здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473833

Comment: Помогите!!! Одолевают. Дали удачный пример, который ввёл в ступор.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу запятой после слова "ранга" (в основном — для *Сержа*)

*Отец, капитан первого **ранга,** и старший брат, мичман, погибли в русско-японской войне.*
Считаю, что указанная запятая все-таки ставится.

[Вопрос № 259346](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить знаки препинания: Отец ? капитан второго ранга ? и брат ? мичман? погибли в русско-турецкой войне.
Объясните, пожалуйста, ваш ответ. Спасибо
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Следует обособить приложения: ***Отец, капитан второго ранга,** и брат, мичман, погибли в русско-турецкой войне.*

Примеры:
*Отец, **капитан первого ранга,** неплохо зарабатывал* (Владимир Козлов);
*Его отец, **капитан первого ранга,** принадлежал к древнему роду из французской провинции Пуату...* (Дмитрий Копелев);
*Ее отец, **капитан второго ранга,** был подводником и надолго уходил в плавание* (Антон Леонтьев);
*Мать работала на верфи диспетчером, а отец, **капитан второго ранга,** сам плавал на контейнеровозе* (Александр Никонов);
*Отец, **капитан третьего ранга,** служил на Черном море* (Елена Бегунова).

Comment: Здесь Грамота лучше, чем ИРЯ РАН...

Comment: Рим, посмотри, пожалуйста, что я [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473922/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0) написал про нас под ответом Шарон.