# Запятая в сложном предложении при общем второстепенном члене

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и, ссп

*В лесу было тихо(,) и только сверху волнами шумело.*
Должна ли здесь стоять запятая? Желательно объяснить, почему нет или почему да)

Comment: Здесь неправильно используется союз "и". Ему здесь не место. Потому что части неоднородные, перед присоединительным союзом ("только") "и" не положено. Это как: *Он купил сок, и только более дешёвый.* "И" вообще не в тему.

Comment: @oleedd Нормальное предложение (из Пришвина, с запятой). "Только" здесь частица. Аналогичных примеров с "и только" – масса.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да миллион процентов, что так делать нельзя. Вот упрощённый вариант: *Там было тихо, и только море шумело.* Похожие примеры: *Квартира современная, и только холодильник старый. Фильм интересный, и только начало скучное.* Ну нет однородности, "и" соединяет однородные предложения. Второе предложение ограничивает первое. Союзом тоже может быть. Здесь вообще три варианта смысла: *но, однако; лишь сверху; лишь шумело*. Трёхсмысленность не ошибка? Более того, контраст "тихо" и "шумело". Раз шумело, то это уже не тихо. Нужно добавить что-то для смягчения шума (например, "издалека").

Comment: @oleedd Да миллион процентов, что это нормальное предложение. Зачем придумывать ненормальные? При чем здесь однородность? Обычное ССП. Больше в этом вопросе я не участвую.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Они такие же самые, как это. Чтобы дошло. Когда ограничиваем сказанное, "и" не используется. А здесь: *Тихо, и только шум волн.* В этом предложении аж три проблемы, нормальным его считать никак нельзя. Однородность при том! Из словаря: Соединяет однородные члены предложения и предложения, представляющие собой **однородные сообщения**. Если вы на слух не замечаете проблему, то это не значит, что её нет!

Comment: @oleedd  Бесполезно, уже проходили... Вы один всё слышите и точно знаете, как правильно (огромное количество подобных (не таких, как у вас) структур в Нацкорпусе; все там, конечно, ошибаются...). Просто порой невозможно пройти мимо ваших категоричных заявлений. Удачи!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Очень жаль, очень старался. Это точно, что бесполезно. Похожие примеры придумал, вы заметили, что они не очень правильные. Только не замечаете схожесть с заданным примером (говорим про тишину, а потом говорим, что не совсем тишина; говорим про современность, а потом говорим, что не совсем всё современно; говорим про интересность, а потом говорим, что не всё интересно). В Нацкорпусе огромное количество примеров с правильным употреблением, а не с таким. Лучше вдумайтесь и поймите. Такую неоднородность не надо игнорировать. Структура такая: *Было так, и только не совсем.* Норм?

Comment: @oleedd  Тишина – понятие относительное, особенно в природе. Это не *абсолютная тишина* в физике, не тишина в сурдокамере. Пришвин пишет: "В лесу было тихо, и только сверху волнами шумело. Изредка невидимыми путями и внизу проходил сквознячок и шевелил какой-нибудь жалкий листик, спущенный сверху паучком". И вам – вдумываться и понимать. // На ненормальность этого предложения давно бы уже обратили внимание специалисты.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Вы чего-то уже на другое переключились. Понимаю, но шум и тишина не совместимы. Нельзя говорить, что тихо, но что-то шумит. Но это ладно, это, думаю, всем ясно. А вы поймите, что в структуре "*Было так, и только не совсем*" "и" не к месту из-за неоднородности. Никто не станет менять, добавлять или убирать слова в старых произведениях. А тогда грамотный писатель мог сам себя проверять, вместо бригады корректоров. Ну понятно, он любил соединять неоднородное "и": *невидимыми путями и внизу* — как и где, так не говорят (по крайней мере, сейчас), это ещё хуже.

Comment: @oleedd О, боже... Я ж говорю, бесполезно... Шум тоже может быть тихим. // Не "менять, добавлять или убирать слова", а обратить внимание на некорректность, если она есть. // *невидимыми путями и внизу*  – здесь не соединяются *как* и *где*, "и" – частица (= также), относится к предыдущему высказыванию: сверху ветерок налетал волнами, а также снизу изредка. // Усё!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ну так желательно указать, что он тихий, а то диссонанс между словами. По умолчанию же шум громкий. Как они могут показать, что они обратили? Сноску в книге сделать? Сквознячок вверху проносился и вызывал шум волн? Ветерок тоже не может. Шумит как минимум ветер. Вот здесь не надо, частица "и" указывает на то же самое. *Сверху дул ветер, и внизу [тоже] проходил сквознячок* — это неверно, предметы должны совпадать. Будем считать, что это разговорный (хаковый) вариант.

Comment: @oleedd Нет, не будем. Какой шум волн? Ветер, ветерок – неважно, это и так ясно, говорится про лес, листву, которая шумела волнами. И внизу изредка. // Вы меня не переубедите, пишите, сколько хотите.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец А в чём надо переубедить. Вы вроде бы уже со всем согласились (не отрицаете). Листва шумит волнами? Жесть. Вот это да. Это как? Думал, что море рядом. Ну и писатель. Итак, мои позиции: 1) Такой диссонанс между антонимами желательно смягчать. 2) В структуре "*Было это, и только не совсем*" "и" не кстати из-за неоднородности (главное). 3) Уйма вариантов смысла. Уже волны добавились. 4) "И" обозначает полное совпадение: Вверху шумел ветер. И внизу ветер (не сквознячок) шумел. Но в разговорной речи эту норму часто нарушают. 5) Есть ещё одно, но очень сложное, не для комментария.

Comment: @oleedd Ни с чем я не соглашался. Да, шум листвы от ветра очень даже похож на шум волн. Образ.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Думаю, пора согласиться уже. Тут спорить уже не с чем. Всё довольно просто и чётко. Либо аргументы против. Шумело волнами => шумят волны => волны чего? листьев? Вы предполагаете, что шумело шумом волн. Но надо так и говорить: *шумело, как волны*. Сложно догадаться до этого варианта. В общем, не абзац, а просто жесть.

Comment: @oleedd  Не с чем соглашаться. Мне сразу был понятен смысл. *Как змея  – змеёй, как волны – волнами*.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Это базовые вещи. Ну тогда нечего и комментировать. Вариант "просто не согласен" (даже не знает почему) сопоставим с "этот фильм фигня". Это ни о чём. Волнами — это по стандарту о внешнем виде (волнистый, вьющийся, колыхающийся). Мне этот вариант не кажется удачным. Есть стандартный хорошозвучащий вариант: *шумит морем*.

Answer (score 2):

*В лесу было тихо, **и только** сверху волнами шумело.*

Запятая нужна, так как **нет оснований** для объединения двух предложений при наличии общего элемента одиночным союзом И. Это два отдельных сообщения.

Здесь **интересная грамматика**: ССП, соединительный союз И и ограничительная частица ТОЛЬКО. Аналогичное предложение есть [в учебнике Кустовой, стр. 224.](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

**ССП С СОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ СОЮЗАМИ**

6. **Соединительно-ограничительное** грамматическое значение — союз И.

Содержание второй части ограничивает, сужает сферу распространения действия первой части: *Окна были темны, **и только** на самом верхнем этаже горело одно окно.*

**Структурные элементы:** 1) ограничительные частицы только,
лишь во второй части; 2) лексика с антонимическим значением.

Comment: Как вы считаете, однородны ли предложения?

Comment: Думаю, что нет, если считать, что однородные предложения должны быть независимыми. Здесь же явная зависимость одного  предложения от другого, которая обозначена в учебнике прямым текстом: содержание второй части ограничивает, сужает сферу распространения действия первой части. Именно неоднородность препятствует их объединению при наличии общего обстоятельства.

Comment: Поэтому я против союза "и". Если "и только" относится к следующему слову, то нормально, а здесь вроде бы относится не к "сверху" (оно даже так не читается), а ко всей фразе, то есть: *и только  шумело волнами сверху*.

Comment: Я согласна с трактовкой этого ССП в книге. и  у меня нет вопросов. На слух предложение тоже корректно. Таких  примеров в литературе, вероятно, много. Вы смотрели Нацкорпус?

Comment: Без "и" лучше: *В лесу было тихо, лишь сверху волнами шумело.* "И" свойственно употребляться тогда, когда есть однородность, а при неоднородности далеко не всегда удачно.

Comment: Почитайте внимательно учебник. Кустова делит предложения с союзом И на две группы: однородные и неоднородные. Этот тип относится к неоднородным. В моем издании (2013 год) указаны синонимы: ССП с противительно-ограничительным значением. Там частица ТОЛЬКО на правах союза, как  НО, ОДНАКО): Тихо все было..., только изредка небегал ветер (Л.) так что оба варианта правильны по всем показателям.

Comment: Я не о правильности, а об удачности (стилистика) конкретного предложения. Можно ссылку?

Comment: Какую? Я же дала в ответе ссылку на учебник 2004 года. Вам на предложение надо? Оно длинное (Лермонтов, Герой нашего времени), найдите его сами по тем словам, что у меня записаны.

Comment: Просто вы говорили про издание 2013 года.

Comment: Это предложение оттуда. Там еще дополнительно сказано только про предложения-синонимы. Остальное есть в 2005 году. А это предложение красивое, и стилистика хорошая. Но что интересно, там не запятая, а точка с запятой.Тихо было все на небе и на земле, как в сердце человека в минуту утренней молитвы; ТОЛЬКО изредка набегал прохладный ветер с востока, приподнимая гриву лошадей, покрытую инеем. Мы тронулись в путь; с трудом пять худых кляч тащили наши повозки по извилистой дороге на Гуд-гору;

Comment: Но в этом предложении нет "и только", за которое мы говорим. В других пунктах однородные сообщения. Однородности вполне достаточно, чтобы использовать "и". А здесь чрезмерная неоднородность, "и" залезает на территорию союза "но", не одобряю. Кстати, лингвисты иногда одобряют то, что не следует одобрять. Например, Розенталь ломанные конструкции одобрял. И кстати, не всегда частое использование делает правильным.

Comment: Давайте остановимся вот на чем (а то будем рассуждать еще долго). Учебник предлагает два варианта ТОЛЬКО  / И ТОЛЬКО,  считая их СИНОНИМАМИ. Но полных синонимов не бывает, всегда есть какие-то отличия. Вероятно, и здесь они есть — семантические, структурные  и т.д. Каждому предложению больше подходит что-то свое. Не стоит ругать лингвистов, неблагодарное это занятие (оставим его другим участникам…).  А вы решите этот вопрос для себя: какова причина того, что в заданном предложении вы лично выбирает вариант с ТОЛЬКО. Можно коротко объяснить свой выбор (мне и другим участникам).

Comment: @oleedd,у вас филологическое образование есть?

Answer (score 0):

Если в предложении конструкция ***союз И+только*** имеет смысл НО или А(а не как обычно в смысле соединения "вместе с кем-то/с чем-то): "было тихо, но шумело"(если речь про то, что шумело)/"было тихо, а сверху шумело"(если речь про то, что сверху) - то есть *И только* здесь выражает противопоставление, а союз И является союзом в сложносочиненном предложении.

*В лесу было тихо, и только (ОНО) сверху волнами шумело.*

Слова *лишь, только, потому, значит, однако, тем не менее и тд* при союзах называются лексические конкретизаторы  § 3110 и 3121 Русская грамота [вроде тут про это самое](http://rusgram.narod.ru/3108-3135.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%94%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%96%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%AF%20%D0%A1%20%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%AE%D0%97%D0%90%D0%9C%D0%98,%D0%BD%D0%B8...%20%D0%BD%D0%B8) - у меня дислексия, так что этот момент сами)

Однако, если интонационно или контекстно *тихо и шумело* относятся к лесу, то речь идет об однородных сказуемых в распространенном предложении.

То есть допустимо также: "в лесу было тихо и только сверху волнами шумело" - без запятой, если имеется ввиду что-то, что объединяет и то, и другое.

Например:
*Стояла поздняя осень. В лесу было тихо и только волнами шумело.*

*То есть, если есть что-то объединяющее однородные члены в данном предложении, то запятая не нужна, если же этого нет, то, по умолчанию,  запятая нужна, так как интонация прочтения и контекст не известны. Без конкретизации значения однозначно грамотно написать фразу русского языка не представляется возможным.*

Comment: "Только" имеет смысл "но", а "и" не кстати, это союз при союзе. *Тишина, только/лишь листья шумят.* => *Тишина, и лишь листья шумят.* Соединяется неоднородное. Похоже на: *Тишина, и однако листья шумят.*

Comment: @oleedd я описал случай соединения неоднородного, с сохранением границы. Это может не совсем о русской грамматике, но в рамках логики видимо вполне имеет место быть. Бочка дегтя и ложка меда/Бочка дегтя, но ложка меда - какое-то промежуточное состояние, как посмотришь так и будет. Бочка дегтя и только ложка мёда(одна ложка мёда, немного мёда)/ Бочка дегтя, и только ложка мёда. И для усиления противопоставления имеет место быть.

Comment: Оно нормально с номинативными, но не с действиями: *Взять бочку дёгтя и только поставить ложку мёда.*

Comment: @oleedd - не понял причем тут оно и я не думаю, что в русском языка это номинативы, номинативы лучше оставить инглишу прочей латыни. Номинатив, как я понимаю это, например, a cat/the cat - что-то относящиеся к кошкам, то есть предмет относящийся к общему понятию предметов. В русском же слово "кошка" - не номинатив, а название непосредственного животного, это кошка, а все остальные кошки похожи на неё. Поэтому артикли в русском не нужны, в отличие от английского, артикль указывает на принадлежность.

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/882/номинативное

Comment: Как бы объяснить, дело в том, что семантика - это значение слов, а этимология - это происхождение, то есть причина слов, смысл, именованный замысел. Номинатив связан с номиналом, нормой, что-то уравненное с чем-то общим, а Имя, именование, связано с выделением исключительных особенность из общего. Русский язык не всегда семантический, редко семантический, он смысловой, образный, а английский знаковый, номинативный, номинальный.

Comment: @oleedd у слова есть значение, то как его надо воспринимать, реагировать для или от. А есть смысл - причина имени какого-то явления. Вот русский - он причинный, а не реакционный. А английский в результате ряда метаморфоз почти полностью реакционный, констатирующий факты, где факт - это соответствие явления некому правилу, а не причине, то как надо воспринимать что-то. В русском можно переставлять семантические блоки в фразе и смысл сохраняется, в английском такого делать нельзя, ввиду четкой формализации номинативов.

Comment: Просто этот термин использую. Ещё называются назывными предложениями. Но суть не в этом, говорю, что, когда действия, "и" не кстати (в таких случаях).

Comment: А примеры по ссылке нормальные, там нет такого ограничения.

Comment: @oleedd А, я понял, оно - это про "только". )) Вот еще что придумал:  Бочка дегтя, и только ложка мёда - и только ложки мёда не хватает, можно изменить падеж в слове ложка. В случае же:  Бочка дегтя и только ложка мёда - падеж не поменяешь не изменив слово бочка, что говорит о созависимости бочки и ложки. В случае "взять бочку дёгтя и только поставить ложку мёда" глагол не на своем месте "взять бочку дёгтя и только ложку мёда оставить" - так норм, наверное, можно переставлять семантические блоки, но разбивать их нельзя. "взять бочку и оставить только ложку мёда", только ложка - не разбивается.

Comment: "Оно" — это "такая штука", вместо "такое". Но здесь уже другое: в одном предложении говорится, что есть, а в другом — чего не хватает. Во втором случае тоже разное: берём и оставляем. Уже нет такого ограничения. Говорю за смысловую схему: *Было/сделай так, и только не совсем.*

Comment: @oleedd короче, я пришел к выводу, что писать можно и так и сяк, зависит от восприятия и контекста. Ответ получился дурацкий, но исправлять лень)

Comment: Без "и" явно лучше, оно за уши притянуто. Похожий пример: *Здесь тихо, и только собаки гавкают на улице.*

Comment: @oleedd я исправил все, теперь вроде логично вышло) без ерунды.

Comment: Если мы добавляем предмет и относим "только" к нему, то уже звучит нормально. Сравнить: *Никто не знает, {и только он} знает.* В ответе "оно" добавлено. Это кардинально всё меняет.