# "Двое", "трое" без объекта

Tags: грамотная-речь, собирательные-числительные

Никак вот не разберусь! Можно говорить, как в следующем примере, или нет?

*На этой картине двое: мальчик и девочка.*

Если добавить слово ребёнок (то есть в случае, когда на картине не одни дети, а и ещё кто-то), полагаю, будет тогда уже, разумеется, *два ребёнка,* но не *двое детей,* верно? Но всё же в исходном примере *двоих* можно употребить, разве нет? А если бы были обе девочки, без упоминания объекта *двое* было бы по-прежнему допустимо? Ведь не заменишь же просто *двое* на *два* в моём примере.

Comment: Двое - местоимение образованное от числительного. На этой картине они: мальчик и девочка. Два - наверное, больше числительное, буква О решает. По идее, О - это образ, "два образа" (в качестве ереси).

Comment: Да при чём тут "они"!

Comment: При том, что не числительное, а местоимение, заменил на натурально местоимение, смысл в целом не поменялся.

Comment: Что бы ни было, "они" мне не подходит.

Comment: Не подходит для чего?

Comment: Смысл ещё как поменялся! Он в том, что двое, а не они.

Comment: На этой картине они вместе: мальчик и девочка. Конечно, двое дает несколько другие оттенки, но суть не меняется, это не числительное. Это местоимение, которое подлежащее, без него конструкция бессмысленна. Двое позволяет опустить местоимение: "на этой картине эти двое: мальчик и девочка." И вы не ответили не подходит для чего. Походить должно не к чему, а для чего, причина этой фразы какая? Чтобы перефразировать точнее, нужно понимать о чем, собственно, речь идёт.

Comment: А если речь не понятно о чем идёт, то это перефраз как у нейросетки - так у нее и тексты бессмысленные поэтому самому, потому что она идет через синонимизацию, а не через причину.

Comment: Звучит так, будто раньше была названа категория: *Вот картины с детьми. На этой картине двое: мальчик и девочка.*

Comment: @Буратино Не бессмысленные. Смотря какая сетка.

Comment: Не понимаю в чем вопрос. Семеро одного не ждут. У меня семеро по лавкам. На этой картине двое. Стандартные конструкции с собирательным числительным.

Comment: Про смешанный состав был вопрос.

Comment: Ну это устойчивые выражения.

Comment: *Сегодня увидел двоих: мальчика и девочку.* Разве нормально звучит?

Comment: Аа, когда перечисление, нужно обобщающее слово (родовое понятие). Поэтому не звучит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечаю точно по вопросу.

**1. Грамматическая справка**

Двое – это **собирательное числительное**, которое может использоваться как с объектом (предметом счета), так и без него. Во втором варианте это субстантивированное числительное с предметным значением существительного.  Объект как бы подразумевается, но неизвестен.

Собирательные числительные **довольно капризны** (у них избирательная сочетаемость, их не так много), но удобны (их легче склонять по сравнению со счетным оборотом).

У собирательных числительных **два основных значения**: (1) обозначают количество предметов как совокупность, если это нужно; (2) используются с существительными, имеющими форму только мн. числа (ножницы, ворота), а также парными предметами (двое  ботинок/две пары).

**2. Как их можно применить в конкретной ситуации**

*На этой картине ***двое***: мальчик и девочка.*

Если это **самостоятельное** предложение, то лучше сказать «двое детей», тогда объект счета будет назван. Если он назван раньше, то мы говорим «двое».

Не имеет значения то, что пол у детей **разный**: ребенок, дети – это общее название. Кроме того, это существительное с собирательным значением, что нам как раз и нужно.

Если  там есть еще кто-то, то можно обозначить **всю группу:** женщина и двое детей; мы видим женщину и двоих детей.

Если это две девочки, то нужно так и сказать:  На этой картине ***две девочки.*** Другие варианты нежелательны. А вот мальчикам все можно: На этой картине ***два мальчика*** (совокупность не обозначена) или ***двое мальчиков*** (совокупность обозначена).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Шарон! Очень рад, что всё так, как вы написали в третьем с конца абзаце!

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, за принятый ответ. У меня  есть вопросы по двум другим темам. (1) Проверьте, пожалуйста,  "ногти и когти" у Ушакова, мне показалось, что он говорит ко(х)ти и но(к)ти, а у вас наоборот. Или это мне  надо еще раз послушать.  Я могу опубликовать ответ, а то желающих вроде бы нет. (2) Вопрос "на квартире и в квартире". Мне хотелось бы послушать ответы, но вот не отвечают. Может быть, знают, но не хотят? Тогда надо чаще принимать ответы, чтобы "вдохновить" отвечающих. Цитирую комментарий: "Чегой-то, мне кажется, ты плюсиков давно не раздавал. Разве нет достойных вопросов-ответов?"

Comment: Точно, я сразу понял и запомнил правильно, где Х, а где К, просто, когда писал, случайно перепутал. Так я же ответил на тот Римин комментарий! Сказал, что вообще ничего не читал и нечему было раздавать. Ответы я обычно принимаю, если получается выбрать, когда их много. А быстро принимать ответы вы сами меня отучили: сказали, что тогда у других уже нет желания отвечать. Ваш сейчас принял, потому что мне этого довольно, а иногда я жду ещё ответов, меня не устраивают в полной мере имеющиеся.

Comment: Да, вы правы, я вот плюсы часто ставлю в качестве благодарности, а принимаю далеко не все. Но вообще люди обидчивы, так что с любыми негативными оценками лучше воздержаться., а то будете говорить в общем, а они примут на свой счет. Достаточно сказать, что вы цените ответы, и тогда отвечать будут намного охотнее.

Comment: Я легко скажу, что очень ценю ответы, кроме тупых ответов от новичков (от них иногда бывают и хорошие тоже), только где сказать? Вот уже сказал, только почитают тут все?

Comment: Артем! Я, пожалуй, процитирую еще вас, и на этом мы закончим обсуждение: «Спасибо, Рим! Да я и не читал особенно никаких обсуждений. Ничего интересного давно не видел». :( Что подумала Римма, я не знаю. Может быть, она правильно вас поняла. Но не будем углубляться в тему, мне ведь только хотелось понять, почему нет ответов.

Comment: Я тоже не знаю, что она подумала, но если прочитала, то странно, что не ответила. Если неправильно поняла, то можно переспросить, я же не враг какой-то. А под тем, что я интересного не видел, я не имел в виду, что его не было — могло и быть, но я не искал, мне не попадалось. То есть вопросов и ответов вообще не видел долгое время, кроме тех, что щёлкал быстро, когда проверял.

Comment: Смайлик внутри цитаты, Шарон.

Comment: ОК! Я хотела смайлик поставить как надо, а он не вписался. Я и подумала, что без разницы.